# batch file to loop through every file in a folder

Tags: loops, batch-file

i have created a script and wanna it to loop through all the file in a directory..
but i failed to do that..
i create another script to apply the script (change_content)..
here the code,

```
cd \input

for %%f in (*.txt) do (

            echo "%%~nf"
            "D:\deployment code\change_content" .\"%%~nf".txt
    )
```

change_content.bat

```
call :yesterday today -1
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
set "val=%%a"
if "!val:~12,10!"=="0001-01-01" (
>> D:\temp\%1_changed.txt echo !val:~0,12!%day%!val:~22!
) else (
>> D:\temp\%1_changed.txtecho %%a     
)
)
```

**My problem is i cant let the script to read the input file if i put it as variable. I can only put the actual file which not helpful in automate the process?**
this is just part of the code where i point to the input and output direction..
just wondering what should i do at the for /f place..

Would be appreciate if anyone could help on this..thanks :)

Comment: install Cygwin. Use bash. You'll be happier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem as what you listed in bold text above.  The following should work, going from memory, but I cannot test it now as I am without a Windows computer now ( and happy I don't have to have one with me ).

If you are instersted in the main program looping portion, try this:

```
setlocal eneabledelayedexpansion

REM:: take \input as param from command line
set top_folder=%~1
set change_content="D:\deployment code\change_content.bat"

for /f "eol=; tokens=1 delims=" %%t in ( 'dir /b !top_folder!\*.txt' ) do (
  REM:: the /b may or may not give yo the full path you need
  REM:: google this if I am wrong

  set file_name=%%~nt
  !change_content! !file_name!

)
```

If you are interested in the change_content portion, try this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM:: change_content looping over file_name variable.
set file_name=%~1
for /f "eol=; tokens=1 delims=" %%f in ( 'type "!file_name!"' ) do (
  set line=%%f
  REM::  Do your thang in here with !line!.
)
```

Comment: Lemme know if what I added after your last comment is not necessary and I can revert the answer to what it was when you accepted. ( I didn't see the accept until after I submitted the last edit ).  Thanks :)

Comment: hhmm.. in fact i can work with type !file_name! the rest i didn't try..
anyway still working fine :)